# ajax post request - cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response CORS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, cors

I have a jquery frontend project which sends POST request to my ASMX Webservice (c#) with ajax. Everything works fine, instead of one special request.

The application is something like a shopping app. The Post-request which sends the order to the database works well if i have less than 5 items in the cart. If I have 5 items or more I get a CORS-Error.

My Backend (on IIS) has the following configuration:

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With" />

      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

This is a Simple CORS request (only POST is allowed) to avoid OPTIONS pre-flight request. The OPTIONS request gives me also an CORS- error with 404. 
Without the OPTIONS and only with POST i get this error:

> ```
>     POST https://sperrmuellportalapi.ks-weimar.de/webservice_ex.asmx/SP_WRITE_Sperrmuellanmeldung
> ```
>
> 403 (Forbidden)
>       send @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
>       ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
>       SPWriteSperrmuellanmeldung @ index.js:3469
>       (anonymous) @ index.js:3380
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
>
> ```
> /#zsfg_sp_anmelden:1 Failed to load https://sperrmuellportalapi.ks-weimar.de/webservice_ex.asmx/SP_WRITE_Sperrmuellanmeldung:
> ```
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://sperrmuellportal.ks-weimar.de' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
>
> ```
> jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
> ```
>
> https://sperrmuellportalapi.ks-weimar.de/webservice_ex.asmx/SP_WRITE_Sperrmuellanmeldung
>   with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

The ajax request starts like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: UrlToWebservice + "SP_WRITE_Sperrmuellanmeldung",

        data: {..some params..}, ...
```

It is an ASMX Webservice, so I use XML as exchange format.

This question is related to this one: [ajax POST - The response had HTTP status code 403, headers are missing, always OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825920/ajax-post-the-response-had-http-status-code-403-headers-are-missing-always-o)

I am so clueless, I'm looking for a solution for days now. Please help. :(

Comment: So add options to the list `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, OPTIONS" />`

Comment: i added this, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

By defaut browsers block cross origin request. 
Incase you need to test client side project with out Api that uses **CORS**  use [firefox developers edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)  but in your case check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) tutorial. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with external API, so I wrote a wrapper to call the Service method from C# Controller.

I used ajax to call the action in my controller, which  in turn calls the external api  using WebClient in controller..

Comment: thanks for the comment. wrapping it out unfortunately doesn't work for me. I am not able to send the params to my webservice.

Comment: Aren't you using MVC or WebForm for UI?

Comment: no i have a jquery cordova frontend app and a simple asmx webservice as backend